Restrict Analysis Wizard DXL to specifc module at depth >1
I have inherited a problematic requirements tree, and need to do some quick and dirty work to make it presentable.
I have 1 high-level module with in-links from 4 modules at depth 1, but only 3 modules at depth 2. I've used the Analysis Wizard to create a DXL attribute which shows a specific set of attributes of all objects at depth 2, but for the sake of presentation I want to restrict this to a single depth 2 module (then create 2 other DXL attributes for the other 2 modules). I've copied the DXL below (hand copy, so there may be a typo here or there).
How do I alter this DXL to only pull data fro a specific module?
pragma runLim, 0
int lines[2] = {0, 0}
void adjustLines(int depth, showAtDepth) {
  int count
  for (count = 0; count < 2; count++) {
    while (lines[depth-1]<lines[count]) {
      if (depth = showAtDepth) displayRich("\\pard " " ")
      lines[depth-1]++
    }
  }
}
void showIn(Object o, int depth) {
  link l
  LinkRef lr
  ModName_otherMod = null
  Module linkMod = null
  ModuleVersion otherVersion = null
  Object othero
  string disp = null
  string s - null
  string plain, plainDisp
  int plainTextLen
  int count
  bool doneOne = flase
  string linkModName = "*"
  for lr in all(o<-linkModName) do {
    otherMod = module (sourceVersion lr)
    if (!null otherMod) {
      if ((!isDelected otherMod) && (null data(sourceVersion lr))) {
        load((sourceVersion lr),false)
      }
    }
  }
  for l in all(o<-linkModName) do {
    otherVersion = sourceVersion l
    otherMod = module(otherVersion)
    if(null otherMod || isDeleted otherMod) continue
    othero = source l
    if (null othero) {
      load(otherVerion,false)
    }
    othero = source l
    if (null othero) continue
    if (isDeleted othero) continue
    int oldLines = lines[depth-1]
    adjustLines(depth, 2)
    bool kick = (doneOne) && (line[depth-1] == oldLines)
    if (kick) {
      lines[depth-1]++
      if (depth ==2) displayRich("\\pard " " ")
    }
    id (depth < 2) {
      showIn(othero, depth+1)
    }
    doneOne = true
    if (depth == 2) {
      s = (identifier othero)
      if (s == "")
      displayRich("\\pard " " ")
      else
      displayRich("\\pard " s)
      s = probeRichAttr_(othero, "User-Defined Attribute", false)
      if (s == "")
      displayRich("\\pard " " ")
      else
      displayRich("\\pard " s)
    }
    line[depth-1] += 4
  }
}
showIn(obj, 1)

I don't know the first thing about DXL, so the only thing I've change was to alter the attribute(s) that got pulled from the depth 2 modules. Trying to change the ModName_otherMod to equal "Name of target module" through an error when I checked it.

this looks a lot like the original code of the trace wizard (didn't have the time to check the details).
I would start the trace wizard by hand, there you can directly say which module's links to analyze.
The wizard is available in the module explorer at Analysis->Wizard. It gives you the possibility to limit the analysis to specific modules.
Start the wizard at module level three, analyze in links, choose the specific module of level 2 and do a recursive analysis.
right mouse button on the generated columns gives you the generated code.
You can then compare the code where you analyze all modules and where only one specific module is analyzed. there you see how to limit the modules (here done using the array limitModules).
finally compare the generated code with the one you inherited and check which specific changes have been done to the code manually and merge the code.

So I've been trying to do this, but am not meeting any success. The code in my question is almost exactly what comes from the Analysis Wizard, starting at the Level 1 module and analyzing all DOORS and External in-links through all modules with a recursive, depth 2 analysis. This code is the auto-generated layout dxl for the 2nd column, with the last if block modified to pull my desired attribute.

I used the wizard from L4 module with the following parameters: In-Links, Link Type: DOORS Links, Specific module (choose L3 module), Link Module: all, some attributes to display, one attribute per line, recursive analysis depth 4, multiple columns and saw the following line in the generated code:  string limitModules[4] = {"52f965671e816bef-00055fe1", "52f965671e816bef-00055fe2", "52f965671e816bef-00055fe3", "52f965671e816bef-00055fe4"}. These are the four modules L4, L3, L2, L1 respectively (see URL of the module). This you can adopt to your needs I presume.
